# Define a python function time2sec with three optional keyword arguments hour minute and second

Tags: python

for example
1 hour and 2 minutes equals 1*3600 + 2 * 60 = 3720seconds
and we get 3720 seconds after running the program

def seconds  ( " H , M , S  " )

def2sec ( 60 * I + 60 * I + seconds )

return def2sec

tried doing this but still could not run the program

Comment: That code isn't even close to being valid Python.

Comment: well i am still in process of learning...

Comment: I suggest you go through the tutorials on [learnpython.org](http://www.learnpython.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def time2sec(hr, min, sec):
    totalSeconds = sec + min*60 + hr*3600
    return totalSeconds
```

This first line shows the function name, `time2sec` and the three parameters, `hr`, `min`, and `sec`.

```
def time2sec(hr, min, sec):
```

Then we make a new variable `totalSeconds` and calculate that based on the input parameters that came into the function.

```
totalSeconds = sec + min*60 + hr*3600
```

Then we return the answer

```
return totalSeconds
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
answer = time2sec(1, 15, 0)
```

And `answer` will now be `4500`